# Crystal Reports runtime problem in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a .NET Framework 4.5 project (C# language) in Visual Studio 2019.
I'm tryng to use Crystal Reports.

When I write `ReportDocument r = new ReportDocument();` this throw this exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your App.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

In the past the "Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0" used to target the 2.0 CLR for whatever reason.  They have fixed this in later versions but it could be related to your issue.  You will also want to verify you have the .NET Framework 4.x installed (I'm assuming you do).  You might also double check that your project has a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and if not try adding one and see if it helps.

If those don't work, consider installing the latest service pack from SAP for the version of Crystal Reports you're using.  The version of Crystal I use is on SP 30 something.  Those libraries now actually target the 4.x framework.  I don't know the version you're using so I can't provide a direct link but you should be able to search SAP's site for it.

Comment: where should I add that code? I don't have an App.config file...

Comment: my solution is composed by a .NET core 3.1 API project and a .NET Framework 4.5 class library. The reporting is in the class library

Comment: The app.config setting won't work with .NET Core.  Crystal Reports doesn't support .NET Core and that's going to be the big road block.  In order to share code the library would need to be .NET Standard (which will fail making Windows.Forms calls even if it doesn't complain at compile time). That means you would likely have to fall back to less conventional and more fragile approaches. If it's a web-site, you could roll a second API site that runs on the classic .NET framework and call it from your library. Every option will involve rigging some type of interop.